# running ansible playbook against unavailable hosts (down/offline)

Tags: ansible

May be missing something obvious but ansible play books (which work great for a network of machines that are ssh connected) don't have a mechanism to track which play books have been run against which servers and then re-run when then node pops up/checks in? The playbook works fine but if it is executed when some of the machines are down/offline then those hosts miss those changes…I'm sure the solution can't be to run all the playbook again and again.

Maybe its about googling correct terms…if someone understands the question, please help with what should be searched for since this must be a common requirement…is this called automatic provisioning (just a guess)?

Looking for an ansible speciic way since I like 2 things about it (Python and SSH based…no additional client deployment required)

Answer (score 3):

There is an inbuilt way to do this. By using retry concept we can accomplish retrying on failed hosts.

Step1: Check if your ansible.cfg file contain

## retry files

```
retry_files_enabled = True
retry_files_save_path = ~
```

Step2: when you run your ansible-playbook with all required hosts, it will create a .retry file with playbook name.

Suppose if you execute below command

```
ansible-playbook update_network.yml -e group=rollout1
```

It will create a retry file in your home directory with hosts which are failed.

Step3: Once you run for the first time, just run ansible-playbook in a loop format as below with a while loop or a crontab

```
while true
do
ansible-playbook update_network.yml -i ~/update_network.retry
done
```

This automatically run until you have hosts exhausted in ~/update_network.retry file.

Answer (score 1):

Often the solution is indeed to run the playbook again--there are lots of ways to write playbooks that ensure you can run the playbooks over and over again without harmful effects. For ongoing configuration remediation like this, some people choose to just run playbooks using cron.

AnsibleWorks AWX has a method to do an on-boot or on-provision checkin that triggers a playbook run automatically. That may be more what you're asking for here:

http://www.ansibleworks.com/ansibleworks-awx

Comment: Thanks…play books that I have written are indeed idempotent…However, even AWX (thanks for that btw, I hadn't read into it) does not do true PUSH handling of play books based on a machine joining the network for example……running a playbook again and again over the entire host set for just 1 remaining machine that hasn't received the update sounds awfully wasteful…no?

Comment: @eskhool "wasteful" not a correct term. If YOU know that a host was down, rerun your playbook on only that host. If your playbook is idempotent then nothing bad will happen if you rerun the whole thing over. regular Ansible(not awx) is stateless. It does not store any info between runs, it's a regular CLI tool. so it can't know what hosts existed during a previous run.

Comment: @Mxx …wasteful was a figure of speech…still idempotent or not running the playbook against servers unnecessarily is not good design even if it doesn't do anything 'bad'…My point was that I don't' want to track which hosts were down…I understand that regular ansible is stateless … the question is looking for a stateful solution using ansible which checks which hosts have the playbook applied and apply to the remaining as they come up …I can write such a tracker but I am trying to reuse such effort if it exists